# how is the iOS beta schedule?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta, schedule

I am making some planning on my application testing and submission for iOS4.3. Is there anywhere I can know the schedule for release or for beta testing?
I heard that there should be at least 2 weeks lead time after releasing the GM seed before the public release, so that programmer have enough time to submit the application for new iOS, is that true?

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is right, usually they publish a new beta every 2nd week and there's a delay from GM to public release.

But as we're talking about Apple, you never know ;-) 
There is no real schedule, it's there when it's there.

Comment: Bojrn is right. And there is usually 3~4 betas so around 1.5 months from now? (Offcourse... you never know)